# How do i solve $e^{ax}-e^{bx}=c$ for $x$?

Tags: exponential-function, transcendental-equations

How do i solve $e^{ax}-e^{bx}=c$ for $x$?

The constants $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers.
It is the final form of a longer equation that I simplyfied.

Edit: The actual equation I'm trying to solve applies to a radioactive generator of molybdenum-99/technetium-99m in my nuclear medicine department. We want to know what is its exact calibration time.

The equation is:
$A_T = A_M \lambda_T (e^{-\lambda_Mt}-e^{-\lambda_Tt}) / (\lambda_T-\lambda_M)$

$A_T$ is the activity of Tc-99m at elution time monday morning = about 3 Curies

$A_M$ is the activity of Mo-99 at calibration time on sunday = 6 Curies

$\lambda_T$ is the decay constant for for Tc-99m = 0.1152

$\lambda_M$ is the decay constant for for Mo-99 = 0.01051

t is the time between calibration and elution. It's what we want to determine.

The goal is to do the first elution each monday, mesure the activity of Tc-99m obtained (it's usualy between 3 and 3.5 Ci) and find out at what time on sunday the generator was calibrated for its 6 Ci activity of Mo-99. So all the variables are fixed except fot t and $A_T$.

Comment: Except for **very** special $a$ and $b$, numerically.

Comment: There's no way to solve this in general. If $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers less than or equal to 4, it can be solved always. Otherwise, as @AndréNicolas says, it must be solved numerically for given values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: So what you are basically asking for is a generalization, because everyone knows that a, b, and c are real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you are in for a numeric solution, but it can be made simpler.  It looks like you measure $t$ in hours, so it is in the range $10-30$, which means $ax$ is in the range $-.1$ to $-.3$ and $bx$ is in the range $-1$ to $-3$.  I would rewrite the equation as $x=\frac 1a \log (c+e^{bx})$ and iterate, starting with $x_0=20$.  It should converge quickly.

Answer (score 12):

I'll simply reiterate what others have said: There is no general way to solve equations of the form you have. There are a handful of values of $a, b$ for which a solution to $\;e^{ax} - e^{bx} = c\;$ can always be solved: e.g., if $a, b \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, you're in luck. (Of course, if $c = 0$, you're also in luck.)

There are numerical methods for solving such an equation for given values of $a, b, c$. If you have only the general form you posted, I'm afraid there's no all-encompassing solution. But if you have particular values of $a, b, c$ in mind, feel free to edit the post and let us have a look at those values.

Comment: I wish the OP would post some that require numerical methods! :-) +1

Answer (score 9):

Declaring $y=e^x$ gives

$$y^a-y^b=c$$

For large $a$ and $b$ this equation is not solvable: it's either a polynomial of high degree or some other complicated beast. Numerics are the way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $(e^x)^a$ and the same for the second one too.

Now check if $c$ is positive or negative. If +ve, take $(e^x)^b$ common. Now the left thing $((e^x)^a)-1$ is not divisible by $e^b$ anymore. So divide $c$ by $e^b$ (if $c$ has a factor). So the no. of times you can divide it by it is $x$.

Just put $x$ afterwards and surely check.

Just visualize it and then do it. You can use it to solve equations like $(2^m)-(2^n)=56$.

Actually someone gave me the equation above (the one with powers of $2$) and then asked me to find $m$ and $n$. I divided $56$ by $2$ as many times as i can until i reached $7$ ($3$ times). So $n$ is $3$ and $m$ is $6$.

Surely try this too!

Comment: This works fine if $x$ and the base natural, but the context has $x$ real and even if it is, $e^x$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

After you edited, your equation is:

$$
e^{-\lambda_M t} - e^{-\lambda_T t} = \frac{A_T(\lambda_T−\lambda_M)}{A_M\lambda_T}.
$$
Now you want to get a reasonably accurate $t$ by numerics to approximate the true time.

Here is my suggestion: due to the derivative of the left hand side decays very fast to zero, common root finding algorithms like [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (or any other root finding method belonging in the class of Householder's methods) may not converge very well.

You may wanna try the old school [Bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).